# getting consecutive digits regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = 'words here and a num 1311374/104813603 and 2302374/544863603 and 0100374/104563603'
```

I have the following string and I want to extract 7 consecutive digits followed by `/` and followed by 9 consecutive digits e.g. `1311374/104813603`. To do so, I have tried the following

```
reg = r'(?:^|(?<=\s))\d{7,9}(?=\s|$)'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

But this gives me an empty `[]`. How do I tweak my `reg` to get my desired output?

desired output

```
['1311374/104813603', '2302374/544863603', '0100374/104563603']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to extract 7 consecutive digits followed by / and followed by 9 consecutive digits

I think you're over complicating it. You may just use:

```
\b\d{7}/\d{9}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fqDYWA/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'words here and a num 1311374/104813603 and 2302374/544863603 and 0100374/104563603'
>>> print (re.findall(r'\b\d{7}/\d{9}\b', s))
['1311374/104813603', '2302374/544863603', '0100374/104563603']
```